# "gpgkeys: key 7F0CEB10 not found on keyserver" Response while try to install mongodb on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, apt, gnupg

I am trying to install `mongodb` on my `Ubuntu 12.04` Desktop edition. Firstly I hope there isn't any issue w.r.t. installing `mongodb` on Ubuntu Desktop edition.

I am following the `mongodb` manual to [install it on my Ubuntu machine](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). 
 **When** I try to import the `10gen public GPG Key` using the instructions (given in the manual), By

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
```

I get this response:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.WsHkMVxFlM --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10

gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com

gpgkeys: key 7F0CEB10 not found on keyserver

gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Any help or hint in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The command ( `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10` ) has worked for me. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit.

Comment: Even I am on Ubuntu 32-bit Desktop Edition but it still displays the same error message. Is there any chance that the network firewall is causing the issue?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A way to go around firewalls: query over typical port (80):
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10`
Another problem you may have would be a network proxy. If you need to connect to the internet through proxy, export proxy settings to you bash configuration - add line with your proxy address (and if needed: username/password - without it's just `http://proxyserver:port`): 
`export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver:port/`
at the end of file `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Awesome, this fixed my problem as well

Comment: Although I wasn't trying to solve this particular problem, I was having issues with an `http_proxy` (set in environment variables) not being used by apt-key. I even tried `sudo -E` to make it consider environment, didn't work. What **did** work though was invoking apt-key with an additional switch: `--keyserver-options http-proxy=http://proxyaddress:80`, which worked immediately.

Comment: The part that I was missing was using *hkp://* as the protocol when specifying port 80. If you use *http://*, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 7):

like answer of [@aniket-thakur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2396539/aniket-thakur) , You can add `MongoDB public GPG Key` Manually By copy The content of this [Page](http://docs.mongodb.org/10gen-gpg-key.asc) into file `10gen-gpg-key.asc` Then add file using `apt-key add <file>` commend line :

```
sudo apt-key add 10gen-gpg-key.asc
```

Answer (score 4):

The second approach mentioned in this [link](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/04/w-gpg-error-httpppalaunchpadnet-precise.html) worked for me. Manually download the key and add it. The link provides step by step procedure to fix the error happening due to missing key.

PS: Above link goes to my personal blog that has detailed steps on how to do this and a couple of other things you can try out to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t find any key running:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 83FBA1751378B444
```

The solution to me was:

```
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

and the I could finally run "apt-get update"